# How to skip Allure reports generations when no test results are found?

Tags: java, maven, allure

I am running `mvn clean test site` to generate Allure reports but the build fails when no tests where run (because there's no test matching a given test group yet):

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project login-tests: Error during page generation: Error rendering Maven report: Could not generate the report: InvocationTargetException: Could not find any allure results -> [Help 1]

How can I configure allure-maven-plugin to skip report generation instead of failing if there are no test results to process?

Answer (score 0):

Since release 2.2.0 Allure will generate an empty report if no results are found.